# App in Simulator Freezes and gives a black screen when hitting "Stop" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

**In Xcode, when I stop execution of the app, the app (in the simulator) freezes and then the simulator gives a black screen.**

- Sometimes this happens when I change the simulator language or any permissions for the app(like camera or photos).
- This is happening sometimes not always. This is happening in simulator only(not in real device).

Why does it happen?

My Xcode version is 14.3, OS: Ventura 13.0.1, Storage:500 GB, Ram: 16 GB

If I removed app from the memory and restarted the app, still the app gives a black screen. But if I restart the simulator, the app functions normally.
Updated the OS and Xcode, but this issue is not resolved.

Comment: I also face it from time to time, but I don't have a solution, hence the comment. My suspicion is, we force the Simulator to run in x86, since we are not able to support building for Apple Silicon natively, and this causes issues with the Simulator. It might also help if you specify your Mac chip (Intel/Silicon) here.

Comment: It's Apple M1 Pro. @EDUsta